# Why was Carnage edited out of Venom?

Tags: venom

''Venom'''s lead actor Tom Hardy confirmed that the only scenes deleted from the  movie were the scenes including Carnage. I believe Carnage would have been an interesting character to have in the film, and his appearance would have opened a door for him to appear in future movies.

Why did they end up deleting Carnage's scenes - and since they ended up getting deleted, why did they begin shooting with Carnage in the first place?

Comment: I've gone through and edited your question to improve the grammar and general tone, please feel free to revert the edits if you believe I've gone too far.

Comment: @F1Krazy appreciate it, I also wanted to highlight what a character Carnage is in terms of strength and significance, so I wrote so earlier.but thanks !

Comment: probably to lead into film 2 better, the after credits scene hints this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[According to IGN](https://www.ign.com/articles/2018/10/08/venom-director-on-saving-carnage-for-the-sequel-and-casting-woody-harrelson), this was intentional.

> The end credits scene of Venom introduces serial killer Cletus Kasady, played by Woody Harrelson, **in a clear set-up for the introduction of the villain Carnage in a potential sequel**.
>
> Director Ruben Fleischer recently sat down for a one-on-one spoiler chat with IGN wherein he discussed the casting of Harrelson and his reasons for why Carnage wasn't used as the villain of the first Venom movie.
>
> Fleischer explained that the priority of the first movie was to establish Eddie Brock and his bond with the symbiote Venom -- "their relationship is really the most satisfying part of the movie" -- and that **the inclusion of Cletus Kasady was only meant to whet fans' appetites for a sequel**.
>
> "We’d like to think that this movie will expand to other movies and Carnage is, I think, the most beloved of the Venom adversaries, with the exception of probably Spider-Man," Fleischer said. "And so **we definitely didn’t want to include Carnage in this first movie because it felt like we wanted to establish Eddie and Venom** and so that’s why we worked having Riot as our main adversary. But the intention or the ambition was to show that there are legs for the franchise in that **a fan favorite let alone played by Woody Harrelson would be something we could look forward to in the future**."

---

> Why did they end up deleting Carnage's scenes - and since they ended up getting deleted, why did they begin shooting with Carnage in the first place?

I cannot find any explicit mention on this. However, it's not that uncommon for some additional things to be shot without already having confirmed that it will actually be included.

Comment: I see that Marvel filmmakers don't rush and they ALWAYS think of the long run.
Thankyou for your time.

Comment: @masterArSuKa: What specifically are you responding to?

Comment: That they are building a base for Carnage to work upon later ! that always works in sequels, i accept the fact that this movie showed their bonding !